# Can Beneish's model for detecting earnings manipulation be applied to companies in the UK?

Tags: modeling

As I understand it this model derived from data for US companies. Is it valid to apply the model as is to UK companies or does it require any modifications?

Description of the model:
http://www.stockopedia.co.uk/content/the-beneish-m-score-identifying-earnings-management-and-short-candidates-56823

Comment: I see no reason you shouldn't be able to apply it to any market, provided you have the data. However it is up to you to test your results; we do not provide help for developing trading strategies.

Answer (score 0):

UK(IFRS) and the US(GAAP) use different accounting standards - off the top of my head you're likely to have differences at least in the Receivables Index, Margin Index, Asset Quality index due to inventory and costing differences.  For example LIFO isn't permitted under IFRS, which is going to affect COGS and Inventory.  It doesn't mean it's unusable, you'll just have to make sure to convert the statements into a common form.  I don't have experience using the M-Score, and I didn't read much past the factors, but I would hope they outline the standard accounting assumptions for each factor.